# TimeZone list understanding

Tags: php, timezone

Currently i have a list of timezone fetched from php `$tzlist = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::ALL);` which contain 400+ timezone is there any way i can use these timezone [list](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/tividd/td/TWS/SC32-1274-02/en_US/HTML/SRF_mst273.htm) instead of that huge list.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: The list you suggest is not practical. For instance, most Europe switches between CET (GMT+1:00) and CEST (GMT+2:00) twice a year. The latter is not even in your list.

Comment: Sure. We pick the most representative PHP timezone for each colloquial timezone and do an array like `['Eastern Time' => 'America/New_York', 'Central Time' => 'America/Chicago', 'Mountain Time' => 'America/Denver', 'Pacific Time' => 'America/Los_Angeles']`. Works well.

Comment: @marekful I want to improve user experience by giving them a short list current list contain 400+ records

Comment: In that case you could filter PHP's time zones by your own constraint and present the rest only. You could also implement typahead/predictive search function to allow for your users to narrow the list.

Answer (score 1):

What we do is pick a "representative" timezone for each of the timezones we want to show. So, our drop-down looks something like this:

```
<select>
    <option value="America/New_York">US Eastern Time</option>
    <option value="America/Los_Angeles">US Pacific Time</option>
    <option value="Asia/Tokyo">Japan Standard Time</option>
    <option value="Australia/Sydney">Australia Eastern Time</option>
</select>
```

The `value` part is what we save into the database of the user, but they pick based on the "nicer" names they're likely to be familiar with. This also works better than a GMT offset, as it takes into account things like daylight savings automatically.

Another potential option is having the user pick a country first. If you do that, you can then pass the second optional parameter to `listIdentifiers`:

```
DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::PER_COUNTRY, 'AU')
```

which will limit the output to just valid timezones **within that country**:

```
[
    "Antarctica/Macquarie",
    "Australia/Adelaide",
    "Australia/Brisbane",
    "Australia/Broken_Hill",
    "Australia/Currie",
    "Australia/Darwin",
    "Australia/Eucla",
    "Australia/Hobart",
    "Australia/Lindeman",
    "Australia/Lord_Howe",
    "Australia/Melbourne",
    "Australia/Perth",
    "Australia/Sydney",
]
```

Some will even make it easy on you, and spit out only one timezone, which'll let you guess pretty accurately which timezone that user is likely to be using...

```
DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::PER_COUNTRY, 'FR')

[
    "Europe/Paris",
]
```